# docker-compose does not create none-existing variable in .env file

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

This is a setup for laravel project:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.2-cli-buster

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && apt install git -y

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . .

RUN composer install --no-dev

RUN mv ./.env.example .env

RUN php artisan key:generate

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"]
```

Look at this variable inside docker-compse.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  artisan:
    build: .
    environment:
        CUSTOM_VAR: custom-value-from-compse

    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

api.php

```php
Route::get('test', function () {
    dump(env('CUSTOM_VAR')); //CUSTOM_VAR is null
});
```

The above route should dump `custom-value-from-compse` value but it dump`null`, What is the problem here ? It only overide existing variable in `.env` file, I mean if i set `CUSTOM_VAR` in .env file to 'some-value' it does not override it to the value inside of the docker compose

Note: the `CUSTOM_VAR` wil be null even i put it in Dockerfile...

Comment: Hey, can you try changing the last line in your dockerfile to `CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "CUSTOM_VAR=custom-value-from-docker php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"]` , build the image and test it out? I want to confirm if PHP is indeed picking up environment variables at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  artisan:
    build: .
    environment:
      # laravel uses Dotenv to set and load environment variables,by default it will not
      # overwrite existing environment variables. So we set env variables for app container here
      # then laravel will use these env values instead of the same env variables  defined in .env file.
      - "CUSTOM_VAR=custom-value-from-compse"

    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/kevinyan815/fa0760902d29f19a4213b4a16fe0501b#file-docker-compose-yml-for-laravel-L11

Comment: Unfortunately this also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values for variables in docker-compose file. If variables in .env file doesn't exist the default value will be set, otherwise  it will be override it to the value inside of the docker compose.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  artisan:
    build: .
    environment:
        - CUSTOM_VAR=${CUSTOM_VAR_FROM_ENV_FILE:-custom-value-from-compse}
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/